# Promise not calling "then" callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

C#/Dart's async/await feature has spoiled me a little. I noticed that ES7 has a proposal for similar syntax, and that [there is a library](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) that adds that feature to Node.JS apps.

This library doesn't work in the browser. I thought by trying to write my own mini-solution might help me see why, so I decided to try it out, just to educate myself. [This is my attempt so far](https://gist.github.com/MelvIsntNormal/590a4e27376c347188e609d539c5b9e6), on Github Gist. I've included snippets below.

In the `await` function:

```
function await (promise) {

  /* PromiseState declared here */

  var self = {
    result: null,
    state: PromiseState.pending
  };

  function onPromiseUpdate(context, newState) {
    return function (value) {
      console.log("Promise Updated!");
      context.result = value;
      context.state = newState;
    }
  }

  console.log("awaiting");
  // this never shows the Promise to be pending (using example below)
  console.log(promise);
  promise
    .then(onPromiseUpdate(self, PromiseState.resolved)) // this is never called
    .catch(onPromiseUpdate(self, PromiseState.rejected));

  // Shouldn't this not block the app if it's inside a Promise?
  while (self.state == PromiseState.pending) ;
  console.log("delegating");

  /* just returning the value here */
}
```

Example:

```
// is there another way to pass 'await' without a parameter?
unstableFunc = async(function (await) { 
  console.log("running unstable");
  if(Math.random() > 0.5) return Math.random() * 15 + 5;
  else throw "fail";
});

expensiveFunc = async(function (await, x, y) {
  result = await(unstableFunc())
  for (var i = y * 8; i >= 0; i--) {
    result *= i ** y / x;
    console.log(result);
  }
  return result;
});


window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log("about to do something expensive");
  // 'expensiveFunc' returns a Promise. Why does this block the webpage?
  expensiveFunc(10, 2).then(function (val) {
    console.log("Result: " + val.toString());
  });
  console.log("called expensive function");
});
```

When running this, the browser doesn't finish loading. It's to do with the loop I set up to check for the state of a Promise being resolved, but that's not the focus of my question. What I'm wondering is why neither the `then` or `catch` callbacks are being called. When logging, the console never logs a pending Promise, and I always thought that `then` and `catch` executes their callbacks immediately if the future is not pending. Why isn't that so in this case?

Comment: Wow, why are you using infinite loops to check if the promise has been fulfilled?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I'm just as ashamed of myself as you are probably horrified. Within the context of what I'm trying to do, is there a better way to check?

Comment: An infintive loop will block the event loop preventing any event or callbacks from firing indefinitely. Use a breakpoint, or a console.log.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer Huh. Isn't everything in a Promise executes asynchronously? I thought that everything inside a promise wouldn't block the main thread

Comment: no, promises don't have anything to do with making synchronous things asynchronous. If it blocks the event loop, it's going to block it regardless of where it is *when it runs*.

Comment: @KevinB Ahh. Looks like I misunderstood how Javascript handles things like this. I think I have conflated _parallel_ execution and _deffered_ execution. Any chance you could post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Using fibers to implement async/await is... interesting... Personally, I would either use real async with Babel, or use promise-yielding generators with [Bluebird's `Promise.coroutine`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html).

Comment: I would post an answer, if i understood what the code in your question is doing... but i can't decipher it. Where's `promise` coming from? I don't see anything in your code that actually creates a promise.

Comment: @KevinB It's a parameter passed to the `await` function I wrote. It's in the Gist I posted. Now that you mention it though, I should probably include the function header.

Comment: but... that doesn't generate any promises either. You're passing the result of unstableFunc to await, which is a number... not a promise.

Comment: @KevinB The example I posted uses the `async` function I wrote, which returns a promise. I wanted to avoid posting all the code into the question as I just wanted to highlight the important pats. Should I get rid of the link to Github and just paste all the code into the question?

Comment: well... the gist is what i'm referring to, not the code in the question. you have an await function, which is passed to the callback of the async function, that you then call with the return of `unstableFunc`, and inside the await function you treat that value as if it were a promise, but... it's not a promise,

Comment: @KevinB Line 65 shows the `async` function. It's basically a decorator: when the resulting function is called, it immediately returns a `Promise`.

Comment: I must be following it incorrectly, running it does in fact show it to be a promise inside the await func. a rejected promise.

Comment: every `while(true);` is blocking, even if it's `setTimeout(() => {while(true);})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment this line of code is reached/executed:

```
while (self.state == PromiseState.pending) ;
```

your script becomes blocked forever (or until the tab crashes or the browser kills it). While that loop is running, callbacks cannot run (nor can anything else) and therefore your promise state will never change to pending thus causing an infinite loop. Having promises involved doesn't change any of the above.